# Plot histogram with colors taken from colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to plot a simple 1D histogram where the bars should follow the color-coding of a given colormap.

Here's an `MWE`:

```
import numpy as n
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Random gaussian data.
Ntotal = 1000
data = 0.05 * n.random.randn(Ntotal) + 0.5

# This is  the colormap I'd like to use.
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu_r')

# Plot histogram.
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, 25, normed=1, color='green')

plt.show()
```

which outputs this:

[image]

Instead of the color being `green` for the entire histogram, I'd like the columns to follow a color-coding given by the colormap defined in `cm` and the values of the `bins`. This would mean that bins closer to zero (*not* in height but in position) should look bluer and those closer to one redder, according to the chosen colormap `RdYlBu_r`.

Since `plt.histo` doesn't take a `cmap` argument I don't know how to tell it to use the colormap defined in `cm`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `hist` command returns a list of patches, so you can iterate over them and set their color like so:

```
import numpy as n
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Random gaussian data.
Ntotal = 1000
data = 0.05 * n.random.randn(Ntotal) + 0.5

# This is  the colormap I'd like to use.
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu_r')

# Plot histogram.
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, 25, normed=1, color='green')
bin_centers = 0.5 * (bins[:-1] + bins[1:])

# scale values to interval [0,1]
col = bin_centers - min(bin_centers)
col /= max(col)

for c, p in zip(col, patches):
    plt.setp(p, 'facecolor', cm(c))

plt.show()
```

To get the colors, you need to [call the colormap with a value between 0 and 1](http://geetduggal.wordpress.com/2011/08/22/grabbing-individual-colors-from-color-maps-in-matplotlib/). Resulting figure:

[image]

Comment: I hope you don't mind - imgur is _not_ blocked at my work so I went ahead and added your picture. I think both approaches are good solutions to this question!

Comment: Mmm if the image is correct then the code is not doing what I need. The color-coding is associated with the bars _heigth_ and I need it associated with the _bins value_. See @Hooked answer's to see what I mean.

Comment: @Gabriel It's true that Bas's answer does not match the color-coding scheme you want - but it's important to take away that we are using _different methods_, `setp` versus `bar`. Each one has its advantages, the mapping of the colorbar could easily be modified in this answer to get the one you were looking for.

Comment: @BasSwinckels You might be able to use the site url through a proxy (say google translate) to at least _view_ the images, if not edit them.

Comment: Although @Hooked answer is also very good I'm marking this one as accepted since it follows the code provided in the question more closely. Thank you both!

Comment: `bins` and `cols` are both `numpy` arrays so they support own `min`, `max` _methods_

Comment: `plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu_r')` is deprecated in Matplotlib 3.7, use instead `plt.colormaps['RdYlBu_r'']`

Answer (score 19):

An alternative approach is to use [`plt.bar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar) which takes in a list of colors. To determine the widths and heights you can use [`numpy.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html). Your colormap can be used by finding the range of the x-values and scaling them from 0 to 1.

```
import numpy as n
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Random gaussian data.
Ntotal = 1000
data = 0.05 * n.random.randn(Ntotal) + 0.5

# This is  the colormap I'd like to use.
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu_r')

# Get the histogramp
Y,X = n.histogram(data, 25, normed=1)
x_span = X.max()-X.min()
C = [cm(((x-X.min())/x_span)) for x in X]

plt.bar(X[:-1],Y,color=C,width=X[1]-X[0])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

While it isn't what you asked for, if someone else stumbles across this (like I did) looking for the way to do the coloration by height of the bins instead of order, the following code based on Bas's answer would work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Ntotal = 1000
data = 0.05 * np.random.randn(Ntotal) + 0.5
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu_r')

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, 25, normed=1, color='green')
# To normalize your values
col = (n-n.min())/(n.max()-n.min())
for c, p in zip(col, patches):
    plt.setp(p, 'facecolor', cm(c))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I like Bas Swinckels answer, but given that the colormap cm take as parameter a value between 0 and 1, a simpler algorithm would be like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Ntotal = 1000
data = 0.05 * n.random.randn(Ntotal) + 0.5

cm = plt.cm.RdBu_r

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, 25, normed=1, color='green')
for i, p in enumerate(patches):
    plt.setp(p, 'facecolor', cm(i/25)) # notice the i/25

plt.show()
```