# Problem plotting a histogram of grayscale image in python

Tags: image, python-2.7, matplotlib, histogram, grayscale

I have plotted a histogram

[image]

of a grayscale image

[image]

with matplotlib. But the histogram does not look like what I want.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
im=Image.open("lena.pgm")
pxl=list(im.getdata())
print pxl
columnsize,rowsize=im.size

a = np.array(pxl)
plt.hist(a, bins = 255)
plt.title("histogram") 
plt.show()
```

I want the histogram like

[image]

Comment: What features are you after, exactly? The number of bins? The colors?

Comment: @ MadPhysicist There is a blank vertical strip in the produced histogram. I don't want this. And the color of the vertical strip should be the same as the last image

Comment: See this SO answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23062183/4902099. Basically you need to map a range of colors to your data in order to generate the histogram you want.

Answer (score 2):

The gaps in the histogram are due to a poor choice of bin size. If you call `hist(..., bins=255)`, numpy will create 256 bins from the min-value to the max-value of your array. In other words, the bins will have non-integer width (in my tests: `[ 24.        ,  24.86666667,  25.73333333,  26.6       , ....]`).

Because you are dealing with an image with 255 levels, you should create 255 bins of width 1:

`plt.hist(a, bins=range(256))`

We have to write `256` because we need to include the right-most edge of the bins, otherwise points with a value of 255 would not be included.

As for the color, follow the examples in the question [linked in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23061657/plot-histogram-with-colors-taken-from-colormap/23062183#23062183)

```
from PIL import Image
im=Image.open("lena.pgm")
a = np.array(im.getdata())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
n,bins,patches = ax.hist(a, bins=range(256), edgecolor='none')
ax.set_title("histogram")
ax.set_xlim(0,255)


cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('cool')
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=bins.min(), vmax=bins.max())
for b,p in zip(bins,patches):
    p.set_facecolor(cm(norm(b)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`plt.hist()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) method like so:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('lena.png', 0)
plt.hist(img.ravel(), 256, (0, 256))
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]